# What are the alternatives if RTMP and RTMPT both are blocked even at port 80

Tags: flash, jwplayer, rtmp, amazon-cloudfront

We are using cloudfront for video streaming(which internally usage adobe media server) with JWPLayer 5.9.  At few of our clients location RTMP port 1935 is blocked,  then it does fall back on RTMPT at port 80 but even then the error message was "server not found". So appears like RTMPT is also blocked.

HTTP progressive download or HLS works on latest browsers not even IE8. Many corporate clients has IE8 as main browser.

What are the other options(if any)? Help Appreciated.

Comment: HLS should work in JW6 in IE8.

Answer (score 2):

Check and see if you have a Palo Alto Networks Firewall or other "deep inspection" capable device on the net.  RTMP looks like Peer-to-Peer (P2P) networking and is, thus, filtered.

Also, many entities intentionally block traffic that look like streaming video.  Other systems will view it is file transfer over port 80 - which is blocked to prevent IP leakage.   Lastly, rules that are intended to detect HTTP VPNs will also block the encapsulated RTMP over port 80.

You can redirect the traffic to any port - see the Adobe documentation.  Lastly - test any site that uses Flash - if that works, JW player or this should do the trick :

http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/dis...CBECA04D05A1AF

Good Luck

Paul